# Inspection forms questions in Anywhere Inspection application

Tags: maximo-anywhere

We are using Anywhere inspection app 7.6.3 and wanted to know how we can get the inspection form questions attached to the Work order on the mobile app. I have seen in one of the IBM materials that the inspection application does have the form questions.Is it available OOb or would need configuration/customization changes.

Answer (score 0):

Its standard Functionality when you define in maximo under specification tab you will get it directly

Comment: Hi Mohammed, i am looking for the inspection form Q&A to appear in the inspection application.